# How to import prototype getter from custom library using Object.defineProperty()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next, defineproperty

I want to create a reusable library for my projects.
For this exercise, I've got one main library, and then an extension library for "identity" related functionality.

The idea is that I can include the identity module if / when needed, and extend the MainLibrary with a getter to access anything related to identity. Here's my code:

```
// Main library - index.js (Package name: @mainlib)
export class MainLibrary
{
   // ....
}
```

---

```
// Identity library - index.js (Package name: @mainlib/identity)
import { MainLibrary } from '@mainlib';

export function useIdentity()
{
  Object.defineProperty(MainLibrary.prototype, "identity", {
    get: function()
    {
       // Returns an identity object
       return {
          isAuth: function()
          {
             return false;
          }
       }
    },
    enumerable: true
 });
}
```

---

```
// App
import { MainLibrary } from '@mainlib';
import { useIdentity } from '@mainlib/identity';

useIdentity();

const myLib = new MainLibrary();
myLib.identity.isAuth(); // Throws error, identity is undefined
```

If I move the Object.defineProperty code into my App, it works just fine. How can I define this in the extension library and apply it to the MainLibrary class prototype, upon calling useIdentity() in my App?

Oh, I'm building with ViteJS, if that's relevant.

Comment: If you want to build a library, stop using `class` syntax. Just use exports. `import { isAuth } from '@mainlib/identity';` is so much simpler. No need to extend prototypes.

Comment: Looks like you have two copies of *@mainlib* loaded. Can you check (or post) your build output? How did you install these modules? How does the *@mainlib/identity* package declare its dependency upon *@mainlib*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MainLibrary` object in your app is not the `MainLibrary` object you import in your extension, because that imports a local version of that by itself.

To solve the issue, instead make `useIdentity` accept an argument (effectively turning it into what is called a **mixin**):

```
// Identity library - index.js (Package name: @mainlib/identity)
export function useIdentity(context)
{
  Object.defineProperty(context.prototype, "identity", {
    get: function()
    {
       // Returns an identity object
       return {
          isAuth: function()
          {
             return false;
          }
       }
    },
    enumerable: true
 });
}
```

and then use it in your app:

```js
// App
import { MainLibrary } from '@mainlib';
import { useIdentity } from '@mainlib/identity';

useIdentity(MainLibrary);

const myLib = new MainLibrary();
myLib.identity.isAuth(); // false
```